# Stack Views Compressing into a Block in Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, uistackview

So, working on a personal project of mine, after frustrating with Auto-layout constraints, I discovered Stack Views. After watching several tutorials and guides on the topic, I thought to try them out. So I created a new Xcode project and played around with them for a while and they seemed to work fine. However, in the process of implementing them into my larger project, I encountered several problems with them that I hope are errors on my part and not Xcode 8 bugs.

After stacking the views and spacing them out, I got this result which was exactly the effect I was trying to achieve:

[image]

However, when I run it in the simulator, even at exactly the same size as the storyboard, the views all compress together into one fat blocky mess completely unlike what is displayed on the storyboard:

(ignore the green stuff, just to help me with layout)

[image]

//How I stacked the Views

[image]

I stacked everything mainly row by row and then stacked the rows together. Then I constrained the master stackview about 10 points to the leading and trailing superviews && 28 pts to the top layout guide and 40 pts to the bottom layout guide.

How to properly stack these damned views so that it looks exactly the same on all devices and screen sizes? Please try and be as specific as you can, including the content mode, etc.

Comment: I *hate* UIStackView. While *trying* to simplify auto layout, I found it added "under the cover" things to the point I coded things manually. So yeah, I'm not of much help - but since this was exactly what I faced two years ago - I uprooted your question. Well formed and worded, from what I can see you've tried several things, defined what you want, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution as I implement :

**VIEW HIERARCH**

[image]

**SPECIFICATIONS**

*MainStackView*

Constraint: Top - 20, Leading - 10, Trailing - 10, Bottom - 20

Alignment: Fill, Distribution - Fill, Spacing - 20

*Row1*

Constraint: Equal Height to MainStackView with multiplier - 0.1

*Row2*

Nothing

*Row3*

Constraint: Equal Height to MainStackView with multiplier - 0.37

Alignment: Fill, Distribution - FillEqually, Spacing - 10

*Row31*,
*Row32*,
*Row33*

Constraint: Nothing

Alignment: Fill, Distribution - FillEqually, Spacing - 10

*Row34*

Constraint: Nothing, add constraint on small view of equal width to Row34 with multiplier - 0.314

Alignment: Fill, Distribution - Fill, Spacing - 10

*Row4*

Constraint: Equal height to Row1, add constraint on small view of equal width to Row4 with multiplier - 0.314

Alignment: Fill, Distribution - Fill, Spacing - 10

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Pramod that really helped me ;)

Comment: Actually, if you still have it, it would be great if you can send me the xcode file at cobiefisher@gmail.com. If not that's fine, I'm just having some difficulties figuring out which row names correspond to which views, etc.